# Command not found: jdeprscan

Tags: java, jdeprscan

```
(base) User:Desktop user$ jdeprscan JavaStruct.class
-bash: jdeprscan: command not found
(base) User:Desktop user$ java --version
java 11.0.7 2020-04-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.7+8-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.7+8-LTS, mixed mode)
```

I am using above java version and its shows jdeprscan command not found. How to fix this ?

Comment: The command is "jdeprscan" **not** `jdeprcan`.

Comment: Sorry typo here I am using jdeprscan only still doesn't work

Comment: What platform are you on? What is the result of `which java`?

Comment: `/usr/bin/java` is result of which java. I am on mac os.

Comment: How did you install `java`? Because I've never had it install in `/usr/bin` on a mac.

Comment: Installed from dmg file of java11, didn't change any parameters

Comment: No clue what to tell you. Try `sdkman` I guess. That's how I always install it. And it works fine here.

Comment: Worked with sdkman, thanks